# Android Runnable Slowing down my device

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I'm trying to develop an app which gets some data from an HTML webpage and displays it every second.

For that i'm using a runnable in this way:

In the OnCreate() method:

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(mMuestraMensaje);
mHandler.postDelayed(mMuestraMensaje, 5000);
```

And then this other method:

```
    private Runnable mMuestraMensaje = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

           try {
            returned = test.GetSensorData(newString);
            rowTextView.setText(returned);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           mHandler.removeCallbacks(mMuestraMensaje);
           mHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
      };
```

The problem is that if i press the back button, for example, the app starts to behave slowly and until i don't force close the whole app the device runs too slow!

Thank you!

EDIT

This is the whole class:

```
public class HttpExample extends Title {




GetMethodEx test, moredata ;
String returned;
TextView rowTextView, rowTextView2;
LinearLayout ll;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
String newString;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.httpexample);
    rowTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    rowTextView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mMuestraMensaje);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mMuestraMensaje, 5000);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    newString = extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");


    test = new GetMethodEx();
    moredata = new GetMethodEx();

    try {
        String name = moredata.GetName(newString);
        rowTextView2.setText(name);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ScheduledExecutorService executor =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(mMuestraMensaje , 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );

}




    private Runnable mMuestraMensaje = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

           try {
              returned = test.GetSensorData(newString);
           } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
           MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                 rowTextView.setText(returned);
           });
        }
      };
```

}

Comment: is your `mHandler` attached to a separate (non-ui) thread?

Comment: No, it's not. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your program slows down because you are running the thread on the GUI thread. That isn't recommended. However, I notice you are setting text after you are done. Here's a few things you could do.

1. Run the sensor data gathering in a different thread. Update the text by the `runOnUiThread` command.
2. Use an [`AsyncTask`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html&ei=8k3HUMrtFaT-0gHn_YHwCg&usg=AFQjCNE8gLVXz1Hwq4rI8oxRkZNHjhRzpQ&sig2=EGsfg74aNijlfw52vnBHDA&bvm=bv.1354675689,d.dmQ), this seems to be an ideal situation for one.
3. For such a regular occurrence, that doesn't require a UI thread, I would suggest using a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

The simplest to start with would be the first, but I would look carefully at the second option. The first option would be something like this: (Note, you will need to replace MainActivity with the name of your activity)

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(mMuestraMensaje , 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );

private Runnable mMuestraMensaje = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

       try {
          returned = test.GetSensorData(newString);
       } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
       MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
             rowTextView.setText(returned);
       });
    }
  };
```

Comment: Implementig this code i get this error:  Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
 - Syntax error on token "returned", VariableDeclaratorId expected after

Comment: Which two lines? I can't get what you mean :(

Comment: Ahhh, I know what the issue is... Sorry about that. `MainActivity` was intended to be the name of your class, so replace that with `HttpExample`.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach you `Handler` to work on a different thread by using `HandlerThread`. For example:

```
HandlerThread ht = new HandlerThread("nonUiThread");
ht.start();
Handler mHandler = new Handler(ht.getLooper());
```

but more preferably, I would suggest you to use `AsyncTask` in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But apart from using AsyncTask, i still need  the runnable, don't i?

Comment: If you are using Runnable, then you may ditch it because it should be replaced by doInBackground method of AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with this:

```
private Runnable mMuestraMensaje = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        try {
              returned = test.GetSensorData(newString);

           } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }

        HttpExample.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                rowTextView.setText(returned.get(0)+returned.get(1));
                rowTextView2.setText(returned.get(2));


            }

       });

    }

    };
```

Comment: can you describe what you actually did to fix your issue rather than just posting code?